# How to pad numbers with underscore in Java?

Tags: java, number-formatting

How to pad numbers with underscores in Java, instead of the usual zeros ?

For example I want

- 123.45 to be formated to ___123.45 and
- 12345.67 to be formated to _12345.67
- 0.12 to be formated to ***_*__*_*__**.12

I tried lots of stuff and closest I got was this (by using SYMBOLS.setZeroDigit('_');):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormatSymbols SYMBOLS = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        SYMBOLS.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        SYMBOLS.setGroupingSeparator(',');
        DecimalFormat OUTPUT_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("000,000.00", SYMBOLS);

        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(0.01));
        // got 000,000.01
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(0.12));
        // got 000,000.12
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(123456));
        // got 123,456.00
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(123456.78));
        // got 123,456.78
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(1234));
        // got 001,234.00
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(1234.56));
        // got 001,234.56

        SYMBOLS.setZeroDigit('_');
        OUTPUT_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("000,000.00", SYMBOLS);
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(0.01));
        // expected ______._1 but got ___,___._`
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(0.12));
        // expected ______.12 but got ___,___.`a
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(123456));
        // expected 123,456.__ but got `ab,cde.__
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(123456.78));
        // expected 123,456.78 but got `ab,cde.fg
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(1234));
        // expected __1,234.00 or at least __1,234.__ but got __`,abc.__
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_FORMAT.format(1234.56));
        // expected __1,234.56 but got __`,abc.de
    }

}
```

Well, not really close but an empty number if formated right (with trailing underscores):
***_*__**,***_*__**.__

Anyway, suggestions on how to get the expected behaviour?

Comment: `DecimalFormatSymbols.setZeroDigit` is used to set the character to represent zero **and all other digits following it**. ` follows `_` and that's why you are seeing `___,___._`` instead of `___,___._1` Edit: the formatting doesn't work but you get the point I suppose.

Comment: yes, i know how setZeroDigit works but i was asking for a workaround to achieve the expected

Answer (score 7):

```
"_________".substring( num.length() )+num;
```

where `num` is a `String` holding your number. To convert a `double` to a `String`, you can use `Double.toString(myDouble)`.

Comment: Unfortunately `Double.toString( myDouble )` yields `123456.78` instead of `123,456.78`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`StringUtils.leftPad()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29) method from the Apache Commons library.

```
// pad to 10 chars
String padded = StringUtils.leftPad("123.456", 10, '_');
// padded will be equal to "___123.456"
```

Comment: what about 0.01 who should be padded to ______._1 ?

Comment: @Belun You are right, the only way to achieve the asker's requirement is to develop a user method.

Answer (score 2):

Da daaa

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class F { 
  public static void main( String ... args ) { 
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("000,000.00");
    for( double d : new double[]{ 0.01, 0.12, 123456, 123456.78, 1234, 1234.56 }){ 
      System.out.println( 
        f.format(d).replaceAll("0","_").replaceAll("_,_","__")
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
______._1
______.12
123,456.__
123,456.78
__1,234.__
__1,234.56
```

Probably the replacement could be done in one step but I'll let that to you.

Comment: I'm not sure  Marcelo, the OP for instance expects `_____._1` for `0.01`  and not `______.01` . From the original question I took the *"expected ..."*  and test it with assertions. Look here: https://gist.github.com/1125723 So, as per the OP expectations this code does what is  needed.